# Mesos with Spark - Unable to register app with external shuffle service

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle, mesos

I am running standalone Spark with Mesos. When I run a series of SQL statements within SparkSQL context, the statement succeed, but I get annoying WARN like this:

```
 WARN MesosExternalShuffleClient: Unable to register app b55184f5-e851-4e71-8c37-398ef30f71da-0000 with external shuffle service. Please manually remove shuffle data after driver exit. Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unexpected message: org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.mesos.RegisterDriver@7186de48
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.handleMessage(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:120)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.receive(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:81)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:111)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:138)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I was unable to find the solution for this problem.

My relevant spark-defaults:

```
spark.mesos.coarse                                              true
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled                                 true
spark.shuffle.service.enabled                                   true
spark.network.timeout                                           3600s
spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout                              3600s
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors                            0
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors                            3
spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors                        0
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout                     60s
spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout                 5s
spark.dynamicAllocation.sustainedSchedulerBacklogTimeout        5s
```

start-start-mesos-shuffle-service.sh:

```
exec "${SPARK_HOME}/sbin"/spark-daemon.sh start org.apache.spark.deploy.mesos.MesosExternalShuffleService 1
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

kirylm,

If you are running Mesosphere's version of Apache Mesos (DC/OS), I have a tutorial that includes an example on starting up the Spark External Shuffle Service on Mesos and includes an example Spark job that uses the external shuffle service.

Keep in mind that running the Spark External Shuffle Service on Mesos by default will only use the storage available via the Mesos sandbox (which may be too small).  If you would like the shuffle service to use ephemeral storage (Mesos MOUNT volumes), you would have to launch the Spark shuffle service with options like this:

"container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "volumes": [
      {
        "persistent": {
          "size": 99500,
          "type": "mount"
        },
        "mode": "RW",
        "containerPath": "spark_local_dir"
      }
    ],

The SMACK Stack tutorial can be found here:

https://github.com/gregpalmr/smack-stack-tutorial

The main BASH shell script that starts the Spark dispatcher, the Spark External Shuffles Service and the Spark History server is located here:

https://github.com/gregpalmr/smack-stack-tutorial/blob/master/scripts/start-smackstack.sh

The example Spark submit that uses the Spark External Shuffle Service is located here:

https://github.com/gregpalmr/smack-stack-tutorial/blob/master/scripts/run-sample-spark-hdfs-job.sh

Hope that helps,

Greg Palmer,
Mesosphere

Comment: Hi, Greg I saw in your example that you use dynamicAllocation false, meaning in your example for spark streaming with Mesos as scheduler all resource allocation is static?

Thanks in advance.